# Text-To-Speech in Android That Works Offline

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

My friend and I are developing an app that uses deep learning and neural nets to help visually impaired people. We're looking for a way to bring the information that the neural nets get via the smartphone's camera back to the user via voice, thus we need to do TextToSpeech.

However, it's a HUGE, HUGE deal for the users to have the app work offline and as all the other parts of the app are capable of running with no Internet connection (neural nets etc.) we're looking for a way to do TextToSpeech offline. The app's also in Russian, so something that can support multiple languages would be great.

We'd be SUPER grateful for any hints on where to start with offline TextToSpeech on Android in Android Studio, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out. Make sure to add a text input box and button in your xml layout

```
import java.util.Locale;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;

public class TextToSpeech {

    private EditText write;
    private TextToSpeech t1;
    private Button speakbtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_text_to_speech);

        write = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        speakbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.board);

        t1 = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    t1.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                }
            }
        });
        speakbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String toSpeak = write.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                t1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
        });
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Dont forget to shut down text to speech
        if (t1 != null) {
            t1.stop();
            t1.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Benjamin, it worked brilliantly in English, like that's what we've been looking for, man! Is there a way to make it work in Russian too maybe?

Comment: No worries, man, we figured out how to use it in Russian after your response! You saved our life! Thank you so, so, so much!

Comment: Always welcome.

Comment: How does this work? Does it work offline consistently for all the android devices above a specific API level or only certain devices?